# how can I collet data from JSON file in r?

Tags: javascript, r

If in the JSON file it's like:

```
"A": {
  "O": "F(1)", 
  "C": 12, 
  "N": 39783, 
  "D": 4233, 
  "H": 38174, 
  "W": 281, 
  "S": 2624
},
"E": [ { "#1": 382.35 }]
}
```

I need value of C, N,D .....E

Answer (score 1):

You can get the values of individual elements using `library(jqr)`

```
library(jqr)

jq(js, ".A.C")
# 12

jq(js, ".A.N")
# 39783
```

or you can read the JSON into R using `library(jsonlite)`, which will put it into an R data structure (with the JSON the way it is, it will be a list). You then access the elements of the list using the usual list subsetting techniques

```
library(jsonlite)

lst <- fromJSON(js)

lst$A$C
# 12

lst$E
# #1
# 1 382.35
```